# Coq induction hypothesis is wrong

Tags: coq, induction

I'm trying to prove a simple induction on two lists,
and for some reason Coq writes the induction hypothesis wrong.
Here is my proof:

```
Lemma eqb_list_true_iff_left_to_right :
  forall A (eqb : A -> A -> bool),
    (forall a1 a2, eqb a1 a2 = true <-> a1 = a2) ->
    forall l1 l2, eqb_list eqb l1 l2 = true -> l1 = l2.
Proof.
  intros A eqb H1.
  induction l1 as [|a1 l1' IHl1'] eqn:E1.
  - induction l2 as [|a2 l2' IHl2'] eqn:E2.
    + reflexivity.
    + intros H2. simpl in H2. discriminate H2.
  - (* where did l1 = l1' come from ??? *)
```

And here are the hypotheses and goals when reaching the last (commented) line:

```
1 subgoal
A : Type
eqb : A -> A -> bool
H1 : forall a1 a2 : A, eqb a1 a2 = true <-> a1 = a2
l1 : list A
a1 : A
l1' : list A
E1 : l1 = a1 :: l1'
IHl1' : l1 = l1' ->
        forall l2 : list A, eqb_list eqb l1' l2 = true -> l1' = l2
______________________________________(1/1)
forall l2 : list A, eqb_list eqb (a1 :: l1') l2 = true -> a1 :: l1' = l2
```

Obviously, IHl1' involves a `false -> _` so it's useless. Where did the `l1 = l1'` come from??? What am I missing here??? Thanks!!

Comment: Your example is not self contained.  I don't see where `eqb_list `comes from.  Is it a function you just defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: remove the `eqn:E1` in the call to `induction l1`.

This directive asks that the `induction` tactic adds an equality in the statement to be proved by induction.  But if you add such an equality, then it appears in the statement to be proved by induction and this messes up the induction proof.

Comment: I inserted my own definition of `eqb_list` and was able to complete the proof.  I believe you question illustrates a design error in the `induction` tactic, where the treatment of the `eqn:` directive should have been treated differently.

Comment: Indeed, removing eqn:E1 and eqn:E2 from the inductions solved the problem. Is there any easy way of tracking which branch of the induction is ongoing? like eqn:E in destruct?

Comment: I believe the answer to question in the comment is yes, because the `elim` tactic from the `ssreflect`package does it better.  But the extra equality that added in the process is more artificial than for the `eqn:E`variant of destruct.  I believe an wish for improvement should be posted to the Coq developers.