# What is the case_eq equivalent of the induction tactic?

Tags: coq

I want to do induction on an inductive variable, but I want the case to be in the hypothesis as it would with case_eq. For instance, if I did `induction n`, in the base case, I would like to have `n = 0` in my hypotheses. Is there a tactic that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is a bit painful to do, [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) does provide some tactics to do that, but the most instructive is to do it yourself by adding an equality to the induction hypothesis:

```
Lemma foo P (n : nat) : P n.
Proof.
generalize (eq_refl n); generalize n at 1.
induction n.
```

Note that this however is painful as you will need to construct the right equality to use the induction hypothesis.

**edit**: This solution works in the example pointed out by @yves:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Section EqList.

Variables (A : Type) (eqb : A -> A -> bool).
Variables (eqbP : forall a1 a2, eqb a1 a2 = true <-> a1 = a2).
Implicit Types (l : list A).

Fixpoint eqb_list l1 l2 {struct l1} : bool :=
  match l1,l2 with
  | [], [] => false
  | (x1::l1), (x2::l2) => eqb x1 x2 && eqb_list l1 l2
  | _,_ => false
  end.

Lemma eqb_list_true_iff_left_to_right l1 l2 :
  eqb_list l1 l2 = true -> l1 = l2.
Proof.
revert l2; generalize (eq_refl l1); generalize l1 at 1.
induction l1 as [|x1 l1 IHl1]; intros l1'.
- now destruct l1'; destruct l2; auto.
- destruct l1' as [|x1' l1']; [congruence|intros hl].
  destruct l2 as [|x2 l2]; [simpl; congruence|]; simpl; intros heq.
  pose proof (andb_prop _ _ heq) as [h1 h2].
  pose proof (eqbP x1 x2) as [rl rr].
  rewrite rl; auto.
  pose proof (IHl1 l1 (eq_refl _) l2 h2).
  now rewrite H.
Qed.
```

**edit 2**: I had to do the proof in a language I'm more familiar with:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Section EqList.

Variables (A : eqType).
Implicit Types (l : seq A).

Fixpoint eqb_list l1 l2 {struct l1} : bool :=
  match l1,l2 with
  | [::], [::] => false
  | (x1::l1), (x2::l2) => [&& x1 == x2 & eqb_list l1 l2]
  | _, _ => false
  end.

Lemma eqb_list_true_iff_left_to_right l1 l2 :
  eqb_list l1 l2 = true -> l1 = l2.
Proof.
move E: l1 l2 => l1'; elim: l1' l1 E => [|x1 l1 ihl1] [|? ?] // ? [|x2 l2] //=.
by case/andP=> /eqP-> /(ihl1 l1 erefl)->.
Qed.
```

Comment: I fear this does not work, as already hinted too in this previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374201/coq-induction-hypothesis-is-wrong/55380082#55380082

Comment: Dear @Yves, why do you think this doesn't work? You need to generalize over the equational variable but it does indeed work as far as I can see [see the edit]. Of course you pay the price of the added hyp. [excuse my horrible non ssr proving skills]